# CSS getting distorted while using the custom WebUserControl in an ASPx page

Tags: asp.net, css, webusercontrol

I have a very simple Web UserControl derived from System.Web.UI.UserControl. 
At Design Time the user control looks perfect in the VS2008 Pane with all CSS styles. When
I drag n drop this control on an aspx page, the CSS style gets applied but some texts get hidden and the CSS looks distorted.

I have checked the path of the CSS, UserControl and the ASPx page. All are in the same level under root. The aspx page just contains the UserControl in a FORM tag.

Any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: Can you show us the markup and the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

> Found the solution !!!!

VS2008 adds this DOCTYPE by default -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

**Change it to**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
```

> This solves the issue. Stylesheet gets
>   applied properly !!!

Comment: Why do you think this is? You may may looking at a symptom rather than the actual problem itself. Post your markup and let others provide some feedback :-)